# Recyclerview doesn't show the items like on android studio looks

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

[image]
**strong text**
On the left is the image of my phone and on the right android studio. I want to know why on my phone doesn't look like on android studio.

My item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorSecurity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_database"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOption"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="OPCIÓN 1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My recycler in my activity class

```
recyclerOptions = findViewById(R.id.recyclerOptions);
        recyclerOptions.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        lm.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        recyclerOptions.setLayoutManager(lm);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not following guidelines outlined in [ask] and [mcve].  Also do not put links in the question, explain the problem, what you have tried, what fails, what else you want, ...

Comment: Hello Jhan, I think at your item.xml, your cardview, you make as wrap content for the width. change it to matchparent

Comment: Please share your layout for the list item so that we can help.

Comment: I shared my code, I hope you could help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your adapter item, .xml class set the height

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

your adapter will automatically set